# javascript verify is a number or only letters

Tags: javascript, verification

I know there are other questions similar to this one, but I ask anyways, I am trying to verify a zip code has only numbers entered, and name has only letters entered. I tryed some of the isNaN, but that wasnt working. Here are the codes im trying to verify with.

```
if(first_name.length < 2){
    alert("Please enter your first name.");
    return false;
}else if(zip=="" || zip.length < 5 ){
    alert("Please enter a valid zip code.");
    return false;
```

I had tryed something like this

```
}else if(zip=="" || zip.length < 5 || zip == isNaN ){
    alert("Please enter a valid zip code.");
    return false;
```

Comment: is `/[a-zA-Z]+/.test(letters_only_string)` and `/\d+/.test(num_only_string)` not good enough?

Comment: Use a regex for something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy solution: regexp

Test 5 digit number

```
/^\d{5}$/.test(your_string);
```

Test if only characters (at least 3):

alert(/^[a-zA-Z]{3,}$/.test(your_string));

Play with it:

http://jsfiddle.net/BAKpY/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a valid zip code composed of only numbers, you need more than that to be sure that's valid.

```
var ext = null;
ext = $("#inputId").value.match(/a-zA-Z/)[1];
if(ext != null){
   alert("Please enter a valid zip code.");
}
```

Comment: you clearly have errors in your snippet. you matching value property of the string to regex, which (value property) most likely doesnt exist for string.

Comment: Actually it works, depends if you are getting the value of a div(.html().match) or an input(.value.match). .match()[1] returns the rest of a string after the first match. Remember this is just a checking for letters

Comment: you updated the code and it still wrong. you should either use `$(..).get(0).value` or `$(...).val()`